# Why does \xC3\xA9 invalidate a JSON file?

Tags: json

I'm generating a JSON file with a [Bash script](https://gist.github.com/kirkins/d1544b3b9d9d6bf910214dce0668fde3) that converts “Kampai-Privé” to “Kampai-Priv\xC3\xA9”.

Why is the following invalid JSON?

```
[{
    "ssid": "Kampai-Priv\xC3\xA9",
    "security": "on",
    "bitrate": "24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s"
}]
```

Comment: Because that's not JSON syntax. It should be `\u00e9`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams but it's in quotes shouldn't it just be considered a string?

Comment: It's still not a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The JSON Data Interchange Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) states that a valid JSON string cannot contain a sequence like `\xC3`. You need to use \u followed by 4 hexadecimal digits.

> [image: screenshot]

In the case of *é* ([*Latin small letter E with acute*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm)) that would be `\u00E9`.

The following is valid JSON.

```
[{
    "ssid": "Kampai-Priv\u00E9",
    "security": "on",
    "bitrate": "24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s"
}]
```